# Issue with listnum track changes in OpenXml(Revisions)

Tags: openxml

I have turned on the track changes(Revisions) option in word and made some changes and found all the track changes were being tracked and found in the openxml content. but i am not seeing the deleted listnum value in openxml content and the listnum values are continued from the next paragraph. so how can I track/get the deleted listnum value in openXml.

More details on the issue - we have 5 paragraphs with listnums (a) to (e). I turned on track changes and deleted listnum value (b) so that second paragraph has no listnum now. I thought I might get the value (b) in openxml since I turned on track changes but I am not able to get the deleted value (b) from openxml.

Thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 1):

A single bulletpoint may use the following xml. It's a single Paragraph containing the text 'Item1' in a Run. The ParagraphProperties applies the style 'ListParagraph' and refers to a numbering:

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph" />
    <w:numPr>
      <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
      <w:numId w:val="1" />
    </w:numPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Item1</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

If Track Changes is enabled and I delete the text 'Item1' I get xml like the following:

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph" />
    <w:pPrChange w:author="Daniel Brixen" w:date="2017-02-16T09:37:00Z" w:id="0">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph" />
        <w:numPr>
          <w:numId w:val="1" />
        </w:numPr>
        <w:ind w:hanging="360" />
      </w:pPr>
    </w:pPrChange>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:del w:author="Daniel Brixen" w:date="2017-02-16T09:37:00Z" w:id="2">
    <w:r>
      <w:delText>Item2</w:delText>
    </w:r>
  </w:del>
</w:p>
```

Two things to note:

- The deleted text is in a DeletedRun-element
- The change in paragraph-properties is recorded by a ParagraphPropertiesChange-element.

So you should be able to find the deleted text by using something like this:

```
  using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\temp\test.docx", true))
  {
    var deletedText = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<DeletedText>();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", deletedText.Select(t => t.Text)));
  }
```

Using Open XML Productivity Tool is helpful when debugging stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel,

We don't want to delete the whole paragragh, we just need to delete the numbering of the paragraph. 

For example - In a list numbering paragraph containing 3 paragraphs. If I delete 2nd  list number Without deleting the Text of the paragraph after turning on track changes, now list number 3 becomes 2 and so I am not able to get the deleted value 2 in second paragraph. it contains only text, not the deleted list number.

Comment: Ok. The list numbers: 1,2,3, a, b, c, I, II, III etc are not part of the paragraph text - they are defined by the stuff in numbering.xml and referred to by using <w:ilvl> and <w:numId> in a paragraph.

Comment: Yes i know, but i am not able to get the deleted list number value using track changes.

Comment: Yes that's a bit weird - the <w:pPrChange> contains a reference to the numId that was used, but not which 'level' was used.